# Subsetting in R by values from a vector

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have a large dataset with column Brand. I do some aggregation and select only a brands fulfilling conditions. This brands are assigned to a vector.

Then I want to subset whole dataset the way it returns only rows which contain brands that are specified in vector

It looks like this: `radegast2final3<-radegast2[radegast2$Brand==vector1, ]`

After running a command I get `Error: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"`

Also I get a subset which includes some of the rows wchich are correctly subseted but there are also many rows which are not present even though they should be

Comment: You probably won't get much attention for your question without specifying exactly what your question is and including some code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you looked into the `%in%` operator? i.e. `radegast2final3<-radegast2[radegast2$Brand %in% vector1, ]`

Comment: You're welcome. Congrats on your first question on SO. @MattO'Brien's advice for question research and formatting is valuable for future inquiries.